# How to break if statement's condition in jinja

Tags: django, jinja2

I am trying to divide media files based on their file type. I have one big if statement's **condition** do this task. But when I am trying to break if statement's **condition** into multiple lines like below it causing an error.

#### My Code:

```
<div>
    {% for post in posts %}
        <h3>{{ post.title }}</h3>
        {% if ( (".jpg" in post.media_file.url) or
              (".png" in post.media_file.url) ) %}
          <img width="500" height="400" src={{ post.media_file.url }}></img>
        {% else %}
          <video  width="500"
                  height="400"
                  controls
                  controlsList="nodownload"
                  src={{ post.media_file.url }}>
          </video>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
```

#### Error:

```
Django Version: 3.0.7
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
Invalid block tag on line 16: 'else', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
```

It is working fine if I convert **if statement condition** like below,

```
{% if ".jpg" in post.media_file.url or ".png" in post.media_file.url %}
```

So, is there any way or how to break **if condition** properly in jinja2?

Comment: afaik no, django template cannot parse that new line conditional position _(like python)_. Better you to built your own templatetags to process specific conditional.

Comment: As @binpy mentions, [custom templatetags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-template-tags/) are a good way, a second option would be to create an `is_image(self)` method with the `@property` decorator, put the large if into it and then only test for `post.is_image` in the template.